# Creating dynamic query to fetch entries from DB based on multiple where conditions

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

Below is the Build entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "build")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Build {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(
            fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
            cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinColumn(name = "job_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = false)
    private Job job;

    @Column(name = "build_url", nullable = false)
    private String buildUrl;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

Below is my repository to perform the transaction with DB:

```
public interface BuildRepository extends CrudRepository<Build, Integer> {
    
    List<Build> findByStatus(@Param("status") String status);

    @Transactional
    @Modifying(flushAutomatically = true, clearAutomatically = true)
    @Query(value = "update Build set status = ?2 where id = ?1")
    void updateBuildStatus(int id, String status);
}
```

If I have to get the entry for particular id I can use findById() on my repository.

Now, I want to fetch the entries from the table based on id, job and name. At least one of the id, job and name will be not null. Can someone help me construct dynamic query which can handle this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data's Specification or Hibernate's Criteria API for creating dynamic queries.

https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications
https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-criteria-queries

Comment: Thanks @yerlikayaoglu for the reply. The problem was resolved by adding below method to my repository :

    @Query(
            "select j FROM Build j where (:Id is null or j.id = :Id) and (:job is null"
                    + " or j.job = :job) and (:name is null or j.name = :name)")
        List<JenkinsBuild> findByIdAndJobAndName(
                @Param("Id") Integer Id,
                @Param("Job") JenkinsJob Job,
                @Param("Name") String Name);


This article was helpful:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-null-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @yerlikayaoglu for the reply. The problem was resolved by adding below method to my repository :

```
@Query("select j FROM Build j where (:Id is null or j.id = :Id) and (:job is null or j.job = :job) and (:name is null or j.name = :name)")
        List<Build> findByIdAndJobAndName(
                @Param("Id") Integer Id,
                @Param("Job") JenkinsJob Job,
                @Param("Name") String Name);
```

This article was helpful:

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-null-parameters

Answer (score 0):

You may simply use a library like this one which lets you build very advanced search queries (supports logical operations, comparisons, enums, dates, joins, functions and much more): https://github.com/turkraft/spring-filter